# iosSlider for multiple pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, swipe

I am trying to use the [iosSlider](http://iosscripts.com/iosslider-jquery-horizontal-slider-for-iphone-ipad-safari/) for multiple pages. 
For example, to swipe from `page1.html` to `page2.html` to `page3.html`, and so on.
The example just shows how to go from one div to another (and I guess the DIVs have either images or text). Does anyone know how to manipulated this to go pull up a new html page?

This is the code on the iosSlider page:

**jQuery:**

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = '/iosSlider/jquery-1.7.min.js'></script>

<!-- iosSlider plugin -->
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = '/iosSlider/jquery.iosslider.js'></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- slider container -->
<div class = 'iosSlider'>

    <!-- slider -->
    <div class = 'slider'>

        <!-- slides -->
        <div class = 'slide'>...</div>
        <div class = 'slide'>...</div>
        <div class = 'slide'>...</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* slider container */
.iosSlider {
    /* required */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    width: <slider width>px;
    height: <slider height>px;
}

/* slider */
.iosSlider .slider {
    /* required */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* slide */
.iosSlider .slider .slide {
    /* required */
    float: left;

    width: <slide width>px;
    height: <slide height>px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* basic - default settings */
    $('.iosSlider').iosSlider();

    /* some custom settings */
    $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
        snapToChildren: true,
        scrollbar: true,
        scrollbarHide: false,
        desktopClickDrag: true,
        scrollbarLocation: 'bottom',
        scrollbarHeight: '6px',
        scrollbarBackground: 'url(_img/some-img.png) repeat 0 0',
        scrollbarBorder: '1px solid #000',
        scrollbarMargin: '0 30px 16px 30px',
        scrollbarOpacity: '0.75',
        onSlideChange: changeSlideIdentifier
    });

});
```

*Or if you know of another plugin or code to swipe from one page to the next, I'd accept that answer as well.*

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

no code available for this yet.

Answer (score -1):

well, you could use the Full-Screen example that comes with iosSlider. It does what you want, if you're willing to place the entire page inside the div.